# Не переведена метка участника Bot

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Духу в комментариях добавили метку `Bot` - надо бы перевести. Пример [вопроса](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1331666/178988).

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Уже изменили. Всё по-русски.